# Generic update stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a generic stored procedure that can update any field value in any table, including fields of type DATE or INT or VARCHAR. How can I can accomplish this with preconfigured generic variables?

Comment: You could just as well google this

Comment: Not sure if the OP meant that table and/or field shall also be selected via a variable. This this wouldn't be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl SET date_col='2012-10-14', int_col=12345, char_col='foobar' WHERE ...
```